# How to add the Interest field in profile page which links the user with similar interest?

Tags: users

I have seen this type of field in drupal.org where some fields appeared as links which lists the users with similar interests or country. Don't know how to do that in Drupal7.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using taxonomy and the term reference field. Each term assigned to an entity has the option in the display mode to be a link to the term page, which in turn shows all entities tagged with that term.

Edit-

Since default term pages only look for content entities you will have to create a view to override those term pages to show user entities instead. You  can use the taxonomy views integrator module to selectively choose which terms use which view. https://drupal.org/project/tvi

Comment: I actually add the term reference field in user account Manage fields tab.Firstly I made the taxonomy name GENDER with terms MALE & FEMALE.After that I add the term reference 'Gender' to user account setting fields.So a link appears on the user account page(MALE or FEMALE),but when I click that link the page appears says "There is currently no content classified with this term."So can you be more descriptive.Thanks

Comment: Until you actually add other accounts with those terms they will be empty.

Comment: Already done that.Add two user account with same term but same result.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on my mobile and can't check but perhaps the default term pages only filter for content entities and not the user entity. You may have to override the term pages with views to be able to add the user entity instead.

Comment: And indeed this is the issue. See https://drupal.org/node/1016942